# How to escape curly braces in a format string in Rust

Tags: string-formatting, rust

I want to write this

```
write!(f, "{ hash:{}, subject: {} }", self.hash, self.subject)
```

But since curly braces have special meaning for formatting it's clear that I can't place the outer curly braces like that without escaping. So I tried to escape them.

```
write!(f, "\{ hash:{}, subject: {} \}", self.hash, self.subject)
```

Rust doesn't like that either. Then I read this:

> The literal characters {, }, or # may be included in a string by preceding them with the \ character. Since \ is already an escape character in Rust strings, a string literal using this escape will look like "\{".

So I tried

```
write!(f, "\\{ hash:{}, subject: {} \\}", self.hash, self.subject)
```

But that's also not working. :-(

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Is it a runtime error (i.e. output you don't expect), or a compile time error?

Comment: It was a compile time error. But it's resolved with the answer by nos.

Comment: Oh, in future, please include compiler output, and preferably the version. This is especially important for Rust since the compiler can change dramatically; which is the case here, the behaviour on master (which I guess is the docs you were reading), differs to 0.11.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

You might be reading some out of date docs (e.g. for Rust 0.9)

As of Rust 1.0, [the way to escape `{` and `}` is with another `{` or `}`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#escaping)

```
write!(f, "{{ hash:{}, subject: {} }}", self.hash, self.subject)
```

> The literal characters `{` and `}` may be included in a string by
>   preceding them with the same character. For example, the `{` character
>   is escaped with `{{` and the `}` character is escaped with `}}`.