# What is the "standard" way to concatenate strings?

Tags: rust

While I understand basically what `str` and `std::string::String` are and how they relate to each other, I find it a bit cumbersome to compose strings out of various parts without spending too much time and thought on it. So as usual I suspect I did not see the proper way to do it yet, which makes it intuitive and a breeze.

```
let mut s = std::string::String::with_capacity(200);
let precTimeToJSON = | pt : prectime::PrecTime, isLast : bool | {
    s.push_str(
        "{ \"sec\": " 
       + &(pt.sec.to_string()) 
       + " \"usec\": " 
       + &(pt.usec.to_string()) 
       + if isLast {"}"} else {"},"})
    };
```

The code above is honored by the compiler with error messages like:

> src\main.rs:25:20: 25:33 error: binary operation `+` cannot be applied to type `&'static str` [E0369]

And even after half an hours worth of fiddling and randomly adding `&`, I could not make this compilable. So, here my questions:

- What do I have to write to achieve the obvious?
- What is the "standard" way to do this in Rust?

Comment: Minor point: knowing whether something is last or not is generally more complicated than knowing whether something is first or not; so I would encourage taking the habit of predicating on "is first" rather than "is last".

Comment: How are you calling `precTimeToJSON`? Just in a loop?

Comment: @MatthieuM. All but the last one get a trailing comma :) So it is the special case. But I still wait for a PHD thesis on the topic showing that something like map or fold can be used without the index to produce output where the last item has no item separator lol

Comment: @BitTickler: Actually, it's a common "mistake" to think that the behavior is inextricably tied to the last one; however you can reformulate it as "all but the first one get a leading comma", in which case you move from special behavior on last to special behavior on first, and the latter works as is with streams of unknown length :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Rust compiler is right (of course): there's no `+` operator for string literals.

I believe the [`format!()` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format!.html) is the idiomatic way to do what you're trying to do.  It uses the [`std::fmt` syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html), which essentially consists of a formatting string and the arguments to format (*a la* C's `printf`).  For your example, it would look something like this:

```
let mut s: String = String::new();
let precTimeToJSON = | pt : prectime::PrecTime, isLast : bool | {
    s = format!("{{ \"sec\": {} \"usec\": {} }}{}",
        pt.sec,
        pt.usec,
        if isLast { "" } else { "," }
    )
};
```

Because it's a macro, you can intermix types in the argument list freely, so long as the type implements the [`std::fmt::Display` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) (which is true for all built-in types).  Also, you must [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25570140/1830736) literal `{` and `}` as `{{` and `}}`, respectively.  Last, note that the format string must be a string literal, because the macro parses it and the expanded code looks nothing like the original `format!` expression.

Here's a [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=mod+prectime+%7B%0Apub+struct+PrecTime+%7B%0A++++pub+sec%3A+u32%2C%0A++++pub+usec%3A+u32%2C%0A%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn+main%28%29+%7B%0A++++let+mut+s%3A+String+%3D+String%3A%3Anew%28%29%3B%0A++++%0A++++let+precTimeToJSON+%3D+%7C+pt+%3A+prectime%3A%3APrecTime%2C+isLast+%3A+bool+%7C+%7B%0A++++++++s+%3D+format%21%28%22%7B%7B+%5C%22sec%5C%22%3A+%7B%7D+%5C%22usec%5C%22%3A+%7B%7D+%7D%7D%7B%7D%22%2C%0A++++++++++++pt.sec%2C%0A++++++++++++pt.usec%2C%0A++++++++++++if+isLast+%7B+%22%22+%7D+else+%7B+%22%7D%22+%7D%0A++++++++%29%0A++++%7D%3B%0A%7D&version=stable) to the above example.

Two more points for you.  First, if you're reading and writing JSON, have a look at a library such as [serde](https://serde.rs/).  It's much less painful!

Second, if you just want to concatenate `&'static str` strings (that is, string literals), you can do that with zero run-time cost with the [`concat!()` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.concat!.html).  It won't help you in your case above, but it might with other similar ones.

Comment: An excellent answer, however given the use of `push_str` and the presence of `isLast` parameter I suspect that the OP is accumulating values from a loop into a single `String`. In this case, it would be more efficient in the loop body to use the `write!` macro which appends to the writer rather than repeatedly creating a `String` with `format!` only to copy its bits into `s` and discard it.

Comment: You can also use raw strings to avoid escaping the double quotes.

Answer (score 4):

[`Itertools::format`](http://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.format) can help you write this as a single expression if you really want to.

```
let times: Vec<PrecTime>; // iterable of PrecTime
let s = format!("{}", times.iter().format(",", |pt, f|
    f(&format_args!(r#"{{ "sec": {}, "usec": {} }}"#, pt.sec, pt.usec))
));
```

`format()` uses a separator, so just specify `","` there (or `""` if you need no separator). It's a bit involved so that the formatting can be completely lazy and composable. You *receive* a callback `f` that you call back with a `&Display` value (anything that can be Display formatted).

Here we demonstrate this great trick of using `&format_args!()` to construct a displayable value. This is something that comes in handy if you use the [debug builder API](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.debug_struct) as well.

Finally, use a raw string so that we don't need to escape the inner `"` in the format: `r#"{{ "sec": {} "usec": {} }}"#`. Raw strings are delimited by `r#"` and `"#`  (free choice of number of `#`).

`Itertools::format()` uses no intermediate allocations, it is all directly passed on to the underlying formatter object.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this madness:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = std::string::String::with_capacity(200);

    // Have to put this in a block so precTimeToJSON is dropped, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/closures.html
    {
        // I have no idea why this has to be mut...
        let mut precTimeToJSON = |sec: u64, usec: u64, isLast: bool| {
            s.push_str(&( // Coerce String to str. See https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/deref-coercions.html
                "{ \"sec\": ".to_string()      // String 
                + &sec.to_string()             // + &str    (& coerces a String to a &str).
                + " \"usec\": "                // + &str
                + &usec.to_string()            // + &str
                + if isLast {"}"} else {"},"}  // + &str
            ));
        };
        precTimeToJSON(30, 20, false);
    }
    println!("{}", &s);
}
```

Basically the operator `String + &str -> String` *is* defined, so you can do `String + &str + &str + &str + &str`. That gives you a `String` which you have to coerce back to a `&str` using `&`. I think this way is probably quite inefficient though as it will (possibly) allocate loads of `String`s.

Comment: I would not that this is quite inefficient all things told, as it creates 3 intermediary `String` objects (which allocate memory) only to discard them immediately.

Comment: I think the closure reference must be `mut` because it mutates its captures.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. @MatthieuM. Yeah I meantioned that in the last sentence.

Comment: I also wondered now a few times why i have to make closures mutable. Right from the stomach I would smell foul if that is really "by design". Should the captures not be a run-time initialization when the closure is being invoked rather than "stateful" as to the closure instance? Hm... maybe picking wrong words for it.  But a function is not mutable - so why would closures be?

Comment: If you can mutate the captures, the closure needs to be be mutable. That applies even if you capture by reference. A closure is both the function and the state it *closes* over, so that's where the need comes from.

Comment: @bluss Maybe this is why they called it "closure" and not "lambda".

Comment: The Rust reference says `|x| x + 1` is a lambda expression and it produces a closure value of an anonymous closure type. Oh and you only have to make it mutable if the closure needs it, rust has inference for the kind of closure.