# "decimal literal empty" when combining several strings for a regex in Rust

Tags: regex, rust

I'm looking to parse a string to create a vector of floats:

```
fn main() {
    let vector_string: &str = "{12.34, 13.}";
    let vec = parse_axis_values(vector_string);
    // --- expected output vec: Vec<f32> = vec![12.34, 13.]
}

use regex::Regex;

pub fn parse_axis_values(str_values: &str) -> Vec<f32> {
    let pattern_float = String::from(r"\s*(\d*.*\d*)\s*");
    let pattern_opening = String::from(r"\s*{{");
    let pattern_closing = String::from(r"}}\s*");
    let pattern =
        pattern_opening + "(" + &pattern_float + ",)*" + &pattern_float + &pattern_closing;
    let re = Regex::new(&pattern).unwrap();
    let mut vec_axis1: Vec<f32> = Vec::new();
    // --- snip : for loop for adding the elements to the vector ---

    vec_axis1
}
```

This code compiles but an error arises at runtime when unwrapping the `Regex::new()`:

```
regex parse error:
    \s*{{(\s*(\d*.*\d*)\s*,)*\s*(\d*.*\d*)\s*}}\s*
        ^
error: decimal literal empty
```

According to other posts, this error can arise when escaping the curly bracket `{` is not properly done, but I think I escaped the bracket properly.

What is wrong with this regex?

Comment: Do you want to capture both numbers or just the first one ? Your code makes it harder to notice but you have two levels of grouping.

Comment: Both numbers, actually, I want also to be able to capture every number of the following configurations : {12.34}, {12.34, 56.7, ..., 8.9}

Comment: You mean an array of floats, all between { and } ? This would be a very different regex

Comment: It is what I want to match, but actually I managed to build it after your hint on the escaping of the curly bracket

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems in your code:

1. [Escaping a `{` in regex is done with `\{`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.1.0/regex/#escape-sequences).
2. Your `.` matches any character and doesn't take what you want. You must escape it.
3. You're capturing more than just the number, which makes the parsing more complex.
4. Your regex building is unnecessary verbose, you may comment without it.

Here's a proposed improved version:

```
use regex::Regex;

pub fn parse_axis_values(str_values: &str) -> Vec<f32> {
    let re = Regex::new(r"(?x)
        \s*\{\s*        # opening
        (\d*\.\d*)      # captured float
        \s*,\s*         # separator
        \d*\.\d*        # ignored float
        \s*\}\s*        # closing
    ").unwrap();
    let mut vec_axis1: Vec<f32> = Vec::new();
    if let Some(c) = re.captures(str_values) {
        if let Some(g) = c.get(1) {
            vec_axis1.push(g.as_str().parse().unwrap());
        }
    }
    vec_axis1
}

fn main() {
    let vector_string: &str = "{12.34, 13.}";
    let vec = parse_axis_values(vector_string);
    println!("v: {:?}", vec);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c34149f213c494626e9946af793d097c)

If you call this function several times, you might want to [avoid recompiling the regex at each call](https://docs.rs/regex/1.1.0/regex/#example-avoid-compiling-the-same-regex-in-a-loop) too.

> I want to be able to match `0.123`, `.123`, `123` or `123.`, the use of `d+` would break these possibilities

It looks like you want to fetch all the floats in the string. This could be simply done like this:

```
use regex::Regex;

pub fn parse_axis_values(str_values: &str) -> Vec<f32> {
    let re = Regex::new(r"\d*\.\d*").unwrap();
    let mut vec_axis1: Vec<f32> = Vec::new();
    for c in re.captures_iter(str_values) {
        vec_axis1.push(c[0].parse().unwrap());
    }
    vec_axis1
}
```

If you want both:

- to check the complete string is correctly wrapped between `{` and `}`
- to capture all numbers

Then you could either:

- combine two regexes (the first one used to extract the internal part)
- use a Serde-based parser (I wouldn't at this point but it would be interesting if the problem's complexity grows)

Comment: Using the escaping with \ did the trick, which is weird as I thought for curly bracket you could also use the double bracket {{ (according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569865/how-to-escape-curly-braces-in-a-format-string-in-rust)

Comment: I would recommend using `\d+` instead of `\d*` because elswise you would also match `.` which is not what you want (and also performes better on some implemenetations)

Comment: Actually I am not sure about the last point as I want to be able to match 0.123, .123, 123 or 123., the use of d+ would break these possibilities

Comment: @DenysSéguret, yes indeed I was confusing format strings and regexes, thank you for pointing that out